# Is there only one way to define a norm from an inner product?

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Given an inner product $\langle,\rangle$, we can define a norm by $||x|| = \langle x,x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$. My question is, are there other ways to derive a norm from an inner product space and if not, how can one prove it?

Comment: $\|x\|=\lambda (x,x)^{1/2}$ for each $\lambda>0$ is also a norm.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways, for example $||x|| = 2\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$.

If you want to exclude all norms of the form $K \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$, then you need to specify what you mean by "deriving from".

Comment: By "deriving from" I mean defined in any way possible under the assumption that you're working with an inner product space.

Comment: This is still not a rigorous definition. If you actually want a proof that no other norms can be "derived", you need to define mathematically and precisely what you mean.

Comment: Well does it make more sense if I put it this way: Given an inner product space, what are all the possible ways you can define a norm on that space?

Comment: That's still not a rigorous description.